# Monodroid/Android - Equivalent of NSAction

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am using monodroid and I am converting an iPhone application to android, and in the code I came across this which is only meant for iPhones

```
public void method(NSAction successCallback)
    {
...
}
```

what is the equivalent of NSAction for android/C#?

Comment: could you tell us what a NSAction is in iPhone?

Comment: @Vee i was hoping you guys would know

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an `[Action<T>][1]` or perhaps a delegate?  These are more of a C# thing than an Android or iOS thing, but otherwise there really isn't anything.

Another thought would be to raise an event instead of having `method(NSAction successCallback)` invoke the callback.

Comment: I figured it out all you have to do is change `NSAction` to `Action`